# How to assign the variables of an array to elements in querySelectorall [Pure Javascript]

Tags: javascript, css, arrays

I am trying to assign the values of an array to elements that were selected by the querySelectorAll function, Any help is appreciated. The code I am trying to write that when the viewpoint of the browser is below 768px, the text changes to the ones in the array, I have tried all the methods I could think of

```
var newb = document.querySelectorAll("#buttonsize button")
var arSizes = ["Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "Large", "XX-Large"]
    for(var i = 0; i < arSizes.length; i++) {
      newb[i].textContent = arSizes[i]
   }
```

It gives this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'textContent')

I also tried doing `newb.textContent` and also using a `forEach` function.

Comment: `newb` has less items than `arSizes`. Make sure you have enough.

Comment: It seems newb is either not available or it does not have enough items as compare to arSizes, both should contains equal number of items

Comment: what happens if you do `for(var i = 0; i < newb.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't enough buttons in html so better listing or buttons firstly

```js
var newb = document.querySelectorAll("#buttonsize button");
var arSizes = ["Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "Large", "XX-Large"];

Array.from(newb).forEach((btnEl, index) => {
  btnEl.textContent = arSizes[index]
});
```

```html
<div id="buttonsize">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
  <button>6</button>
</div>
```